# view php msg in alert javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have an php variable contains string, got from a function, and wants to view it in alert message in javascript, well, I tried to that

```
    var tmp='<?php echo $BillMsg; ?>';
    alert(tmp);
```

But the alert didn't show up, in the console I found this error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

I tried to define a random php variable like the follwoing

```
    <?php $test="test";?>
    <script> alert(<?php echo $test; ?>); </script>
```

It works fine, but when using the variable $BillMsg, it won't work? Whats wrong?

Comment: What's in the source?

Comment: code is in js file or php

Comment: try alert('<?=$BillMsg?>');

Comment: `$BillMsg` most likely contains some character that breaks the JS script. For example, you probably should escape `'` characters.

Comment: no the javascript is in the same php page

Comment: You have a *JavaScript* error, look at the JavaScript, not the PHP. Find out why you have an error first. (Then consider looking at the PHP so you stop generating it).

Comment: alert("<?php echo $variable_name; ?>"); is always working fine for me.

Comment: can you post what $BillMsg variable holds?

Comment: Here's some advice: if you're trying to inject PHP into JavaScript (and you are) always look at the output (your JavaScript file). Chances are you accidentally caused a syntax error. You're not going to find that in your PHP file.

Comment: If you have some "bad" characters in $BillMsg this would help: var tmp = <?php echo json_encode($BillMsg) ?>;

Comment: $BillMsg contains this String "No Calls Available";

Comment: I tried alert('<?= $BillMsg?>'); it still the same!
but when using alert('<? echo json_encode($BillMsg);?>');
it works, but with quotes around the string, how to dispose them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you see is a JS error, which means that either there's a problem with your JS code (perhaps some other part of the front end code you're not showing us is flawed). Alternatively, the PHP value is causing problems. The way to easily insert PHP values in JS is through `JSON`:

```
var tmp = <?= json_encode($someVar); ?>;
//<?= is short for <?php echo
alert(tmp);
```

That shouldn't cause any trouble, no matter what the value of `$someVar` is.
With your updated code snippet, the issue is that the value of `$test` is not being quoted when passed to the `alert` function. Change it to this, and it'll work:

```
<?php $test="test";?>
<script> alert(<?= json_encode($test); ?>); </script>
```

Comment: @user3710166: You're welcome, but please: read the help section. If an answer to your question was helpful/fixed your problem, you are asked not to leave _"thanks"_ comments, but rather mark that answer as accepted

Comment: Thanks again, I'm new to stack overflow, and I tagged  the answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function msg1(){
        var msg = document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML;
        alert(msg);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
       echo "<p id='msg'>Here is my string</p>";
    ?>
    <input type="button" onclick="return msg1();" value="button"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score -3):

what about this

```
<?php 
$BillMsg = isset($BillMsg)? $BillMsg : "$BillMsg not set";
?>
var tmp='<?php echo $BillMsg; ?>';
    alert(tmp);
```

Comment: this does not work either!